# DownloadOperation Callback not executed Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Hey everyone I get this code from background download transfer from msdn, and I modify this a little bit

```
private async Task HandleDownloadAsync(DownloadOperation download, bool start)
{
    bool finish = false;
    try
    {
        LogStatus("Running: " + download.Guid, NotifyType.StatusMessage);

        // Store the download so we can pause/resume.

        activeDownloads.Add(download);
        DownloadData newData = new DownloadData();
        newData.DownloadOp = download;
        downloadData.Add(newData);
        Progress<DownloadOperation> progressCallback = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(DownloadProgress);
        if (start)
        {
            // Start the download and attach a progress handler.
            await download.StartAsync().AsTask(cts.Token, progressCallback);
        }
        else
        {
            // The download was already running when the application started, re-attach the progress handler.
            await download.AttachAsync().AsTask(cts.Token, progressCallback);
        }

        ResponseInformation response = download.GetResponseInformation();

        LogStatus(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Completed: {0}, Status Code: {1}",
            download.Guid, response.StatusCode), NotifyType.StatusMessage);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        LogStatus("Canceled: " + download.Guid, NotifyType.StatusMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (!IsExceptionHandled("Execution error", ex, download))
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    finally
    { 
        finish = true;
    }

    if (finish == true)
    {
        //Something todo here
        activeDownloads.Remove(download);
        downloadData.RemoveAt(ind);
        finish = false;
    }
}
```

I tried this on emulator and the "finally" line executed right after download progress finish, but I try this on real device and the finally line doesn't executed. it doesn't give any error, and doesn't get anything on catch line.

Comment: How are you calling `HandleDownloadAsync`? Are you perhaps blocking on it using `.Result` or `.Wait`?

Comment: I just use 
await HandleDownloadAsync(download, true);

Comment: And no logs are written?

Comment: I read the log file and no cancellation even triggered, but I try to release the App, and it works without no error. I still don't know what happened, but now it works correctly, thank you sir